# Spring boot + Primefaces + JPA + PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to develop a spring-boot app with primefaces, jpa and PostgreSQL. I was able to start the application with primefaces integration without problems but when I add jpa dependencies, app throws:

> Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector and org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.

I'm a newbie with spring boot framework, I follow different guides and I've read carefully the doc, but after some day I'm unable to resolve this configuration problem. Here is my

> POM.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>it.kinapp</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>testproject</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    <joinfaces.version>4.6.1</joinfaces.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootsfaces-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces1-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
                <artifactId>joinfaces-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>classpath-scan</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>joinfaces-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Inside webapp folder, I've created WEB-INF folder which contains

> beans.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
```

and

> faces-config.xml

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
          version="2.2">
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
    </resource-bundle>
    <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
</application>
```

For sure the issue is caused by a mistake during the project configuration due to my inexperience with the framework.

Can someone explain to me where is the error, and which are the right dependencies to include to make the project runnable?

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

SOLVED.

I hope it's useful for somebody, I haven't add in pom, in dependencyManagement tag the spring boot dependencies, now the updated pom is

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: It will benefit everyone if you post your solution not as an edit to the question, but as an answer to it. That way you can get points for both, and the question will show up in searches as having an answer.

Comment: Thank's for the advice but I can't answer my own question due to my low reputation, in the futere I'll do.